How to handle ODBC UserData in Lua
I'm new to Lua Script. I'm trying to connect MSSQL DB using lua-odbc
https://github.com/moteus/lua-odbc
I'm able to connect and get data from MSSQL using below code
--print("ODBC Connectivity started")
odbc = require "odbc"
cjson = require "cjson"
dbassert = odbc.assert

-- Dynamic Input from USER
local tableName = "dbo.Table1";
local selectFields = "Field1,Field2";
local limit = "10"
local condition = "";
 
cnn = odbc.connect('DBNAME', 'USERNAME', 'PASSWORD')

local sqlQuery = 'SELECT TOP '.. limit .. ' ' .. selectFields .. ' FROM '.. tableName;
print(sqlQuery)

stmt = cnn:execute(sqlQuery)
print(getmetatable(stmt))
local myTable = {};

stmt:foreach(function(f1,f2)
  local valueArray = {};
  valueArray.f1= f1;
  valueArray.f2= f2;
  table.insert(myTable,valueArray);
end)

local json_str = cjson.encode(myTable);


--print(json_str)
assert(stmt:closed()) -- foreach close cursor
assert(not stmt:destroyed()) -- statement valid


Is there a way to dynamically handle UserData returned from cnn:execute
For example :
If user wants to include field3 how can I include field3 in my table while iterating UserData

If UserData contains only Field1 and Field2 then it definitely knows nothing about Field3. To add it, you need to start over from local selectFields. It is not really a Lua problem.
